# Como aplicar estilo a um elemento a partir do valor do do mesmo usando CSS

Tags: css

Boa tarde, eu gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de aplicar estilo a um elemento a partir do valor dele. por exemplo...

```
<p>Ola mundo</p>


p(mundo){

  background-color('blue')

}
```

no caso todo o paragrafo ficaria com a cor de fundo azul.

Existe essa possibilidade?

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua ideia, mas se você quer mudar o estilo do parágrafo em específico "Ola mundo", basta fazer `<p style="background-color:blue;">Ola mundo</p>`

Comment: Infelizmente nao pode ser assim, pois eu vou atribuir essa cor dinamicamente caso exista o mundo por exemplo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só sei de um jeito de fazer algo semelhante, e mesmo assim precisaria ter o mesmo texto do tag em um `dataset`, ai sim daria para usar um seletor CSS por Atributo para pegar o texto.

Aqui tem um exemplo, repare que a primeira e a última linha possuem o texto "blue", dentro da tag `<p>` e tb no `data-text`, com isso eu uso o `p[data-text*="blue" i]` para pegar qualquer menção ao texto `blue` (`*`), independente de caixa alta (`i`), e usar como seletor para aplicar a cor azul.

```css
p[data-text*="blue" i]{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor blue sit amet.">
  Lorem ipsum dolor blue sit amet.
</p>
<p data-text="Lorem, ipsum dolor.">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor.
</p>
<p data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet BLUE consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, nobis.">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet BLUE consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, nobis.
</p>
```

Resumindo, se tiver a palavra `blue`, dentro do texto do `data-text`, vai aplicar a cor azul a tag `<p>`